# Prevention of phone number detection is not working on HTC device

Tags: html, htc-android

I have to prevent detection of Phone number in my application.

I am using:

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content ="telephone=no"/>
```

meta tag in my html. This prevents the phone number detection on Xolo device. But it doesn't work on HTC device. Is that a device specific issue? Which workaround can I use to prevent the phone number detection in all devices?

P.S: In my case, date field is being picked up as Number. And the dialer screen is being opened upon clicking a date. (Date format: DD-MM-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worked. And finally, I had to change the date format as DD/MM/yyyy.

That somehow prevents opening dialler screen.

Answer (score -1):

On Android and iOS it should work with:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

I'm not sure if the spaces matters in your code, other than that it seems the same.

Comment: This isn't answering anything. The whitespace in this case will not matter, nor will excluding the slash.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, this code should work on Android and iOS devices, as it does for me.

Comment: yes, it should work everywhere. Your answer however doesn't actually solve any issues given the OPs original code (as it is just the same code, or at least, the browser interprets it the same), that is all. I think this may be an edge case for the OP or we don't have enough information at this point.